# AutoPostBack not triggering Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, autopostback

I have an asp ddl setup like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="attendeeList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="tripRegistrationItem" />
```

c#:

```
private void attendeeList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mission = new Mission(Int32.Parse(tripList.SelectedValue));
    person = new Person(int.Parse(attendeeList2.SelectedValue));
    attendeeLabel.Text = person.FullName.ToString();
    ClearInputs(tripRegistrationWizard.WizardSteps[1].Controls);
    LoadAttributes();
    SetInfo();            
    }
```

and:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{            
    attendeeList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(attendeeList_SelectedIndexChanged);
    attendeeList2.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(attendeeList2_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

What I am experiencing is that the `attendeeList2_SelectedIndexChanged` does indeed fire when the selected item of the DDL is changed, and the code within the method is executed, however a Page_Load, Page_Init, Page_PreRender... are NOT raised. It is almost like it isn't doing a true PostBack, yet it is running the code. I am needing to do some things in the Page_PreRender in that OnChange event, but can't figure out how to pull it off.

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is the code that calls `InitializeComponent()`:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //
    // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
    //
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

EDIT 2:
I just realized that the client side control I am working with is inside an Update Panel. It appears that when the control is within an Update Panel, it simply does an AJAX refresh, never raising the Page_Load, Page_Init... Once I pulled the control out of the update panel, it now triggers a full Post Back as I was expecting. Not sure why I couldn't find that tidbit of info while searching around, but now I know.

Comment: Where are you calling InitializeComponent() from? Why are you setting your event handlers from code behind instead of directly in the .aspx page?

Comment: @msm8bball - I edited post to now include the call for InitializeComponent(). As far as setting the handlers from codebehind rather than .ascx, I can't speak to that, as I am not the original author of the code. This is a working usercontrol that I have been been asked to add some functionality to. I am trying to limit any code-behind "redesign", though I can where needed..

Comment: try `base.Init` before `InitializeComponent`

Comment: @Grundy - Tried swapping the order as you suggested. No difference

Comment: Would you attempt this?
`<asp:DropDownList ID="attendeeList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="tripRegistrationItem" OnSelectedIndexChanged="attendeeList2_SelectedIndexChanged" />` and not try to set up the event handler from code behind? See if that makes a difference. It should at least make the code cleaner, even if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @msm8bball Thanks for the idea. I implemented it, and get the same behavior. NOTE: to do this, I had to bump my method from "private" to "protected".

Comment: @gmaness i'm try your sample on a new project and its work, page_load raised

Comment: @gmaness you shure that your dropdown does not empty?

Comment: @Grundy I have a "debug" label on the page. I just keep appending to the .Text property as my live debug. When the page loads, I can see that the full page load cycle fires (page_init, page_load...). When I change the selection in the ddl, all of the code within the event handler method executes, however my flags for page_init, page_load... are not raised. It is obviously posting back of some sort, as the code is executing, yet the page_load events aren't raising, so I am unable to do what I need to in them. I'm sure I am missing something basic somewhere.

Comment: what you mean when say _"my flags for page_init, page_load... are not raised"_?

Comment: I use a label to track what is going on by appending to the .Text property. In the Page_Init event, I append "/Init/" plus the value of IsPostback, in Page_Load I append "/PageLoad" and so on. So, when I first hit the page, my label reads /Init/False/PageLoad/PreRender. When the "postback" happens on the change event, the label does not change at all, where it should change to /Init/False/PageLoad/PreRender/Init/True/PageLoad/PreRender.

Comment: can you provide this code?

Comment: @gmaness, i think you missing something in this code for label, best way check it - set breakpoints on methods what you want check

Answer (score 0):

Please try at the page directive to add:

```
autoeventwireup="true"
```

some like:

```
<%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codefile="yourpage.aspx.cs" inherits="yourclass"%>
```